# Why doesn't this Java tree traversal work?

Tags: java

I'm getting my feet wet with Android Studio targeting a Nexus.  So far it's great, I've found the migration from my .NET comfort zone to be fairly seamless.  Until:

Quite often in .NET I used a pattern of tree traversal, in which each node in the tree is an instance of a class that is derived from a common base class.  I call a 'foo()' function of the root, which calls foo() of each of its descendants, so the call gets propagated around the tree.  Pretty standard really [Dr. Evil voice].

Implementing this in java seems to have sh!t the bed.  Below is code that DOES NOT work in java but works in .NET, and I don't know why.  If I put breakpoints in either of my 'Handle' implementations, none of them are called.  And if I "Step Into" the call to a child 'Handle' implementation, it gets really crazy and halts the program with no exception report.

Should this work?  Thanks for any thoughts.

```
// *************
// BASE CLASS WITH AddChild, Handle
// *************

public class cA
{

public int m_Tag = 0;

protected cA ptr_FirstChild = null;
protected cA ptr_LastChild = null;
protected cA ptr_Parent = null;
protected cA ptr_NextSibling = null;

public cA(int tag)
{
    m_Tag = tag;
}

public void AddChild(cA a)
{
    a.ptr_Parent = this;

    if (ptr_FirstChild == null)
    {
        ptr_FirstChild = a;
        ptr_LastChild = a;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr_LastChild.ptr_NextSibling = a;
        ptr_LastChild = a;
    }
}

public void Handle()
{
    int a;
    a=3;

    cA tmp = ptr_FirstChild;

    while (tmp!= null)
    {
        tmp.Handle();
        tmp = tmp.ptr_NextSibling;
    }
}
}

// *************
// DERIVED CLASS, overrides Handle
// *************


public class cB extends cA
{
public cB(int tag)
{
    super(tag);
}

@Override
public void Handle()
{
    int a;
    a=4;

    cA tmp = ptr_FirstChild;

    while (tmp!= null)
    {
        tmp.Handle();
        tmp = tmp.ptr_NextSibling;
    }
}
}

// *************
// Usage of classes
// build a tree with both cAs and cBs, 
// a cB as a root, with two child cAs.  Then call
// root.Handle, hoping to traverse the tree.
// *************

cA a1 = new cA(1);   // instantiate all leaves
cA a2 = new cA(2);
cB b1 = new cB(1);

b1.AddChild(a1);   // build the tree
b1.AddChild(a2);

b1.Handle();          // call Handle on the root, intending to traverse the tree, but this halts the program
```

Comment: It should work. Is this your actual code?

Comment: Code works for me, where exactly have you set the breakpoints?

Comment: Try to follow Java code conventions: methods start with a lower case letter. Classes start with a capital.

Comment: This is my actual code.  Smutje, did you actually run it?  Are you using Android Studio?  When I put a breakpoint on any Handle call and then "step into" it, my App crashes.  Not so for you?

Comment: Where are your unit tests?

Comment: When the app crashes, do you get an exception? If yes, than what exception do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code runs and traverses the tree at my machine, one thing I may think of a problem are the positions of breakpoints because as your first line of `handle` is `int a;`, setting a breakpoint on this line does not lead to a break, because a pure declaration without initialization is not a valid breakpoint location. On the contrary, setting the breakpoint on the second line `a = 4;` will actually cause a break.

Comment: Oh, you did run it thanks.  If you're using Android Studio, if you "Step Into" a Handle() call, does it crash?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ and no, it does not crash, sorry.

Comment: By the way it pains me to admit it but you were right I was doing that at least at one point Smutje, putting breakpoints on variable defs which were not triggering.  This was part of the problem, and my next step, setting a breakpoint in the caller and stepping in, caused the App crash -- which "confirmed" to me I had a real problem.  So my code actually was working but I seem to be able to crash the debugger.

Comment: Oh boy... I just figured out (I am only a couple of days old with Android Studio) that ALL "step into"s crash my app with no exception report.  What a red herring.